# SignalR hosted in MVC in Azure emulator has cross domain problems from JS client

Tags: azure, signalr, cors

I've got a SignalR hub (named EventHub) hosted in an Azure web role that's an MVC 4 application running in the emulator at 127.0.0.2:81. In my Application_Start, I have:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(new HubConfiguration { EnableCrossDomain = true });
```

in my JS client running via IIS at localhost:1003, I have:

```
$.connection.hub.url = 'http://127.0.0.2:81/signalr'; 
$.connection.hub.start().done(alert('connected'));
```

My client can connect to the hub and call methods on it, but in the console, I'm seeing:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.2:81/signalr/reconnect?transport=longPolling&connectionToken…&tid=0&_=1380138173967. Origin http://localhost:1003 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

The client eventually disconnects itself. If I use the same client, and a nearly identical hub implementation and run it in a stand-alone MVC app at localhost:62835, I get no cross-origin errors at all. I'm running this in Chrome v29. I do not have any custom headers specified nor have I set jquery cors support to true.

Is there some kink that the azure emulator is causing? And if so, is there some way around it?

**UPDATE:**

I've published my web role to Azure, and cors appears to be working in that environment. In addition, Chrome is now using websockets to connect instead of the longpolling that was being attempted when connecting to the emulator-hosted site.

I would still like to be able to run this via the emulator for local testing, so if anyone has any ideas on how to get that working, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get any cross-origin errors via the emulator for local IIS express SignalR app with the latest Azure SDK on Windows8 for the cross-origin scenario, make sure the emulator in your repro is up.